# Is this idiom formal or informal

Tags: word-usage

I came across this idiom "sweaten the deal/pot" and I want to know if I can use it in formal context or not.

Comment: It's ***sweeten***, not ***sweaten***. And it's an informal colloquial expression, so don't use it in formal or legal contexts.

Comment: Also, this phrase often implies you're trying to bribe someone, so it may cause offense if it's not clearly a joke/metaphor.

Comment: Several of your questions ask "Can I use X in a formal context",  but there is a great range of "formality".  In a personal essay, it might be fine.  In a wedding invitation, it would be odd.  In a business letter, it would be strange, as it might be understood as suggesting a bribe. There isn't just "formal" and "informal", there are a whole range of contexts  Generally, formal writing is simple, plain, free from metaphor and fancy English.  In formal writing you say exactly what you mean, rather than use words figuratively.

Comment: +1 with @JamesK that instead of asking whether something is 'formal', OP(s) need(s) to provide exact situation where they intend to use the phrase/expression/word in question. Written form, formal, official, standard etc these are non-specific.

Answer (score 3):

It is sweeten, as FumbleFingers pointed out. It is informal. However, it is not extremely informal. Avoid using it in professional writing or in a press conference. It is okay to use to a coworker or acquaintance.